# Bulk Insert - Row Terminator for UNIX file + "\l" row terminator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

so I have been wrestling a perplexing issue with BULK INSERT for some time.  The files come from a Linux box and when I look at them in hex edit mode/notepad ++ they appear to have just a linefeed (0A) as a row terminator.   I store bulk insert statements in a table which later a job selects from and executes the statement in the table to load data into a staging table.

The particular case that is perplexing to me is a table that has 7 columns.  The data file only has the first 4 columns, the rest should be left NULL.

Typically they look like this:

```
BULK INSERT STAGING_TABLE  FROM 'FILE_LOCATION'  
WITH     (   
DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'
,   FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
,   ROWTERMINATOR = 'something_here'   
);
```

The row terminator has been the biggest source of my issues.

When I try to use "\n" the bulk insert fails on an truncation error-- it seems to treat the file as one long string and only delimits the columns correctly until it runs out of columns (hence truncation error).

When I use "0x0a" the bulk insert fails on "unexpected end of file" error.  There was a blank line at the end of the file but even when I removed that it still threw the same error so I'm not sure what is wrong there.

The ONLY one so far that has worked for getting data actually into the table was "\l".  Does anyone know what that means?  I have searched far and wide but there doesn't seem to be documentation on it.  That or I have been looking in the wrong place completely.

The weird thing with \l as the rowterminator is that even though it load successfully it still doesn't respect the rowterminator...  The rows just get loaded into all 7 columns and split on seemingly random intervals.

Anyone have any idea?  Should I clarify some more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue you are having is actually not due to the Row Terminator. I suspect, along with the End of File error, you also saw something similar to the following:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 4 ({column_name}).

While what I said below the line is still valid regarding the `ROWTERMINATOR`, the real issue is indicated by your statement of:

> [the] table that has 7 columns. The data file only has the first 4 columns, the rest should be left NULL.

This is the issue. When using `BULK INSERT`, the data file has to have the same number of fields as the table being inserted into. If that is not the case, then you have to use the `FORMATFILE ='format_file_path'` option in which case you need to create a [Format File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190393.aspx) and specify the location.

I thought you could get away with the easier [OPENROWSET(BULK...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) so that you can do the following:

```
INSERT INTO STAGING_TABLE
   SELECT *
   FROM   OPENROWSET(BULK 'FILE_LOCATION' ...);
```

But that doesn't allow you to specify a `ROWTERMINATOR` without using a Format File. Hence you need the Format File in either case.

**OR**, you could just import into a different staging table that only has 4 columns, and then either:

- dump that into your current STAGING_TABLE, or
- do an `ALTER TABLE` to add the 3 missing columns (it is more efficient to just add 3 NULLable fields than to transfer the data from one table to another :-).

***OR***, as mentioned by @PhilipKelley in a comment on this answer, you could create a View with just those four fields and have that be the destination/target. And if you were doing the appropriate steps to enable the operation to be minimally logged, the MSDN page for [Prerequisites for Minimal Logging in Bulk Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422.aspx) does not say one way or the other what the effect will be if you use a View.

---

Most likely the `\l` was just interpreted as those two literal characters, hence it not respecting the `rowterminator` when you tried it.

The `0x0A` will work as I have tested it and it behaves as expected. Your statement should look like the following:

```sql
BULK INSERT STAGING_TABLE
FROM 'FILE_LOCATION'  
WITH (   
       DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar',
       FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
       ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A'
);
```

I tried both with and without a `0x0A` character at the end of the final line and both worked just the same.

I then removed one of the commas from one of the lines, leaving it with less than the full set of fields, and that is when I got the following error:

```
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
   Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The 
                 provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Make sure that all of the rows in the data file have the required number of field separators (`,` in this case). You mentioned having 4 columns in the file so that should be 3 commas per row.

Comment: Thanks, the alternative suggestions you made ended being able to resolve my problem.  It was definitely the fact that I have different columns between the data file and the staging table.  I was confused by this though because there are several other processes structured in this same exact way function correctly despite also having mismatched columns.

In any case it all worked out.  Thanks!

Comment: @RazzleDazzle Glad it worked out! Regarding the other similar processes that are working, are you sure that a) they are using `BULK INSERT` and not something like `OPENROWSET(BULK...)` or `BCP.EXE`, and b) if they are using `BULK INSERT`, that they are not also using a Format File? I don't see how it is possible that they could be working with `BULK INSERT` while having a different number of columns and no Format File, unless those columns are IDENTITY or something like that (that cannot be inserted into). PS, which actual fix did you end up going with? Just curious :)

Comment: @RazzleDazzle Just FYI: I just tested again with an extra column in the destination table. Tried it as both a `DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE())` and as `INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)` and both failed due to the mismatch in number of columns. So not sure how those other processes are working without a Format File or using something other than `BULK INSERT`.

Comment: I ended up going with a "staging" staging table with the correct columns into the one with extra.

Comment: Another option for mis-matched bulk insert columns: create a view on the target table that matches the data being loaded. Here, the view would have four columns, you'd bulk insert into the view and the "extra" three columns would pick up the default value (NULL, or define default constraints on them). This is extremely useful if the file and tables columns are in different (or even random) order.

Comment: @PhilipKelley Thanks for that! I never think of Views as something to run DML statements against. But I kinda like that idea more than creating a separate table and transferring the data. I checked the MSDN page for [Prerequisites for Minimal Logging in Bulk Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422.aspx) and didn't see any mention of down-sides to using a view. I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment to ask these but my reputation is not high enough.

I believe "\l" is "linefeed", so that would mesh with you seeing 0A in the file encoding.

My first question would be, what character encoding is your data files in? And what is the datatype on your table columns?

I would guess that this is going to be a character encoding issue. I see your DATAFILETYPE is 'widechar' Did you confirm that your source file is Unicode? And when you insert data and select it back out, does it look as if the character encoding is being preserved?

Comment: The `\l` is just "backslash l". It is not an interpreted escape sequence. The OP is correct in that 0x0A == \n == line feed. But the issue is a field number mismatch between the source file and destination table.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) seems to indicate that using a newline character as the row terminator, `'\n'`, will get automatically translated to `'\r\n'`.  It says that only applies to **bcp**, but clearly something else is going on.

Example C at the bottom of that page says to use this dynamic SQL for Unix line endings:

```
DECLARE @bulk_cmd varchar(1000);
SET @bulk_cmd = 'BULK INSERT AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderDetail
FROM ''<drive>:\<path>\<filename>'' 
WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+''')';
EXEC(@bulk_cmd);
```

That makes it seem like it's a known issue.

If you're retrieving the file from an FTP/SFTP site, can you transfer the file in ASCII mode?  Alternately, can you run the file through any of the numerous [line ending changers](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-convert-dos-newlines-cr-lf-unix-text-format/) like `unix2dos`, or `todos`?

I know SSIS allows you to specify just newlines for row terminators, as does the Import/Export Wizard.  If that's an option, you might look at that.  You have to define your columns in the data files very precisely and it's very tedious for files with a lot of columns, but you generally get a ton more options like quoted field identifiers, etc.

And I have no idea what control character `\l` represents.  It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Comment: I definitely agree with the using of FTP/SFTP/FTPS in order to specify ASCII mode and have it do the conversion. Unfortunately, that alone won't help here as the issue is not with the Row Terminator: the number of fields is different between the source file and destination table and yet no Format File is specified to handle that.